# SSRS - Column visibility disabled

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a group column in my report which I need to show/hide based on a parameter value. Since it's a group column, "Column Visibility" is disabled. I tried setting the "Hidden" property to true, but that leaves a white space which I don't want.

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for this? I tried for various solutions over the net, but none worked for me. Attaching a screenshot on the same.

[image]

Comment: your column having grouping so you can't hide that column.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I want a workaround on this for the report to work, so looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're going to need a different strategy.

Changing the visibility isn't going to work without leaving the blank space and you can't make the entire column not visible because it's the main grouping.

Can you use a different column for the group so you can hide the **Amount Received Date**?

Or use an Expression to change the column to a different field?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to use a different column, since the other condition doesn't use grouping at all. Can you please elaborate more on the 2nd solution you are suggesting "Using an expression to change the column to a different field"?

Comment: Is there some other data that you might display instead of the Amt Rcvd Date? Then you could base the column on the parameter to show either field.  Or you could make it blank. **=IIF(FIELDS!PARAMETER1.VALUE - "SHOW", FIELDS!Amount_Received_Date.VALUE, FIELDS!Amount_Received_Date.VALUE, FIELDS!OTHER_Date.VALUE)** or have the field be blank **=IIF(FIELDS!PARAMETER1.VALUE - "SHOW", FIELDS!Amount_Received_Date.VALUE, FIELDS!Amount_Received_Date.VALUE, "")**. Another solution is to make two tables - on with the column and the other without and display the one based on the parameter.

Comment: Thanks Hannover. The second solution worked. I created two tables and handled it's visibility based on the parameter value.

Comment: Here is a workaround (another strategy) to Hide a Column that is part of a grouping: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37874321/495455